# Acquire single token for multiple scopes microsoft entra id

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, token, msal-react, microsoft-entra-id

I have an asp.net core web api project. This project uses `azure entra id` for `authentication`. I have registered 2 apps in this entra one for react client app and second for asp.net core web apis. This web api project has 2 modules one `mes` which is secured with this scope `"api://********-****-****-****-************/Mes"` and other `user management` which required above `scope` plus these `graph api` scopes,

```
 "User.Read",
 "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
 "User.Invite.All"
```

[image]

Now on react app I'm using `msal-react` and `msal-browser` for login and attaining token but when i am trying to get a singular token for all these scopes so that I get access to all apis with single token I only get token for either `mes` scope or `graph api` scopes

```
const loginRequest = {
  scopes: [
    "api://********-****-****-****-************/Mes",
    "User.Read",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.Invite.All",
  ],
};

const handleLogin = async () => {
  try {
    let auth = await instance.loginPopup(loginRequest);
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(auth));
    localStorage.setItem("access_token", auth.accessToken);
    return auth;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AuthError && error.errorCode === 'user_cancelled') {
      console.log('User cancelled the login flow');
      return rejectWithValue('User cancelled the login flow');
    } else {
      console.error('Login error:', error);
      throw rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
};
```

[image]

[image]

When I'm requesting all scopes together in login request, its only providing token for `graph api`, to get token for `mes` i must request it alone in login request.
Purpose of this question is to find a way that let me get single token for all these scopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer is that you can't.

A token can be acquired for multiple scopes if all those scopes belong to same resource. For example, in a single request you can acquire token for `User.Read`, `Directory.ReadWrite.All` and `User.Invite.All` scopes because they are part of Graph API resource.

To acquire token for your API, you will need to make a separate request as it is a completely different resource.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note** that: You cannot generate access token for multiple resources that is Web API and Microsoft Graph. You need to generate two access token one for API and one for Graph.

Created a **Microsoft Entra ID application** and granted below API permissions:

[image]

Generated **access token** via Postman by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:api://XXX/readaccess User.Read Directory.ReadWrite.AlL User.Invite.All
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

- The access token got generated with the scope as **`api://XXX/readaccess`** but Microsoft Graph scope isn't included in the access token.
- If you are passing multiple resources, then while generating the access token it will consider only the first scope while generating the access token.
- Hence, generate separate tokens for  different resources.

**Reference:**

[I want to get multiple access token for my multiple scopes. How can I do that with only one user sign in? - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1316127/i-want-to-get-multiple-access-token-for-my-multipl) by Shweta Mathur