# Azure Blob Storage fails to authenticate (using msal-browser). Required token scope seems to be missing

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-ad-msal, msal

I'm attempting to put together a tiny (preact, but I don't think that's relevant) app that can retrieve some information from Azure Blob Storage. So far, I can successfully log in using the `@azure/msal-browser`, which (theoretically) means that my app registration in Azure is at least somewhat correct. Now, I'm attempting to access Azure Blob Storage using `@azure/storage-blob`'s `BlobServiceClient`.

I have deduced that my app registration needs the API permission `user_impersonation` for Azure Storage, and I have configured that. I have also added the scope `https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation` to both my login request as well as my `acquireTokenSilent()` request.

The `loginPopup()` call looks like this (in a "Login" component):

```js
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";

export default function Login(props) {
    const { instance, accounts, inProgress } = useMsal();

    const doLogin = () => {
        instance.loginPopup({
            scopes: ["user.read", "https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation"],
        })
    };

    if (accounts.length > 0) {
        return <button onClick={() => instance.logoutPopup()}>logout</button>
    } else if (inProgress == "login") {
        return <span>Login is currently in progress...</span>
    } else {
        return <button onClick={doLogin}>Log In</button>
    }
}
```

I have created a `CustomTokenCredential` class as described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/vue-js-user-authentication/) (which gives an example of this sort of thing using Vue), that simply takes the access token retrieved by `acquireTokenSilent`. That seems to satisfy the `BlobServiceClient`, but the request ultimately fails with a 401 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.)

The call to `acquireTokenSilent()` looks like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!account) {
        return;
    }

    instance.acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: ["user.read", "https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation"],
        account: account,
    }).then(async response => {
        console.log(`acquireTokenSilent got a response`);
        if (response) {
            for (const scope of response.scopes) {
                console.log(`scope: ${scope}`);
            }

            const tokenCredential = new CustomTokenCredential(response.accessToken, response.expiresOn);
            const bsc = new BlobServiceClient("https://myblobcontainername.blob.core.windows.net", tokenCredential);
            const containers: ContainerItem[] = [];

            for await (const container of bsc.listContainers()) {
                containers.push(container);
            }

            setMyData(containers);
        }
    });
}, [account, instance]);
```

The scopes that get logged are as follows:

- scope: openid
- scope: profile
- scope: User.Read
- scope: email

I have noticed that the `acquireTokenSilent` response doesn't include the `https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation` scope, and I suspect that this is the reason for the failed request. I am definitely passing in that scope in the call (as well as in the call to `loginPopup()`; I do not understand why it wouldn't be coming back. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 401 Error means the token is acquired for some scope other than the storage scope. Can you please edit your question and include the code? Thanks.

Comment: @GauravMantri I added the code; I think it's worth pointing out that after adding the azure storage scope the first time (and logging out/back in), I did get the storage service listed in the popup. For some reason, though, the token doesn't have the scope on it.

Comment: I noticed that you are adding `user.read` and `https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation` scopes in the same request. Please note that this won't work. Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78166774/acquire-single-token-for-multiple-scopes-microsoft-entra-id/78167008#78167008. You need to acquire token for storage service separately.

Comment: @GauravMantri aha, that was it! If you want to put that in an answer, I'll mark it!

Comment: IMHO, it would be better to close this as a duplicate of the answer I linked.